# How to install Jar file with parameters innosetup

Tags: java, jar, inno-setup

I'am trying to create a setup with innosetup for my application but before the finish of the installation of my setup.exe i'd like to run other installation by this command :

```
java -jar build.jar buildinfo.xml
```

this Jar installation will takes 45 seconds but i don't know how can i do it .

Comment: `Filename: "java"; Parameters: "-jar build.jar buildinfo.xml"` from the `[Run]` section in a hope the user has installed Java.

Comment: Don't work :(
i found in some forums i must run it by a cmd command ?!!!

but i don't know how do that !!

Help please.

Comment: That could be `Filename: "cmd"; Parameters: "/c java -jar build.jar buildinfo.xml"`.

Comment: the solution is to specify the place exactly of the files
'cmd.exe', '/C java -jar C:\soft\build.jar C:\soft\install_DF.xml

thank's for your help Tlama

Answer (score 1):

Also you can...

- create a batch file with your commands ("java -jar" etc.)
- use "Bat to exe converter" (search on Google) in order to convert
  your batch file in a Windows executable file
- run that exe file at the end of Inno setup procedure

I hope this can help someone :-)